# How to make require_once path dynamic?

Tags: php

I need to make my require_once dynamic so I can get the file no matter where I put the folder containing the file.

I have already tried using `__DIR__` but it doesn't seem to be working.I searched many posts and all of them gave answers the same as this but mine just doesn't work.

```
require_once (__DIR__.'/google-api-php-client-2.2.2/vendor/autoload.php');
```

This is the error I'm getting.I do not have the path var/www/html on my local project.This path was made when my project was placed on the server and it is not able to get the file.
[image]

How do I get the file I need without specifying it to go var/www/html?

Comment: `__DIR__` is the directory of the current `.php` script so any paths you use it in will need to be relative to that directory

Comment: Kinda looks like you haven't executed `composer install` yet so the Guzzle files aren't present

Comment: @Phil then how should i change my code so it gets the file i need?The folder 'google-api-php-client-2.2.2' is in the same folder as my index.php

Comment: That part looks ok. See my second comment for what I suspect is the real problem

Comment: @Phil I didnt get the file from composer.I downloaded the released file from github

Comment: Does `/var/www/html/google-api-php-client-2.2.2/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php` exist? If not, then you either got a corrupt archive or haven't extracted or transferred the files to your server correctly

Comment: Never mind, looks like the maintainers messed up one of the releases. [Re-download the zip file](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases/tag/v2.2.2). See https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1466

Comment: @Phil It doesnt exist on my local project.It doesnt exist when I upload to bitbucket repository as well.So i suspect it exist on the server side but i dont know why it cant locate the file.

Comment: @Phil alright thanks for your help!!

Comment: @PhilWhich asset should i download?I am currently using google-api-php-client-2.2.2.zip.I downloaded this file recently.

Comment: I just download it now and everything is present. I got this file ~ https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases/download/v2.2.2/google-api-php-client-2.2.2.zip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187159/discussion-between-black-leather-and-phil).